# web.config 301s for all files but one

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I'm trying to set up 301s for a site which will bounce all old pages to the homepage (it was a large site that is now a single page).

The server's Windows based, however, so no htaccess fun for me.

Could anybody assist with producing a web.config file that redirects everything to the homepage via 301s?

Comment: Okay... Can you please explain the following logic: "Look! I have a question about IIS. Let's tag it with .htaccess, which is an Apache configuration file, so I summon all the Apache experts."

Comment: Yes - htaccess rules can be adapted for web.config purposes.

Comment: btw, what version of IIS you are using? I suppose 7 or higher

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="301 Redirect Everything To Home" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".+" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="/" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But is will redirect everything, including images, include files etc.

Could you explain your motive for this as generally it's a bad move. It causes a poor user experience, robots don't like it, and nothing knows if a page is really missing or not.

Comment: I originally had a large site hosted on the server, but have since switched to a single page site (index.php being the page). 

I'm trying to avoid manually redirecting every one of the previous pages, so this was an attempt to blanket redirect everything to the new single page.

Images/files redirecting aren't an issue at this stage, as no downloads etc are provided from the single page.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try "IsapiRewrite" 3rd party module/DLL

> ISAPI_Rewrite is a powerful regular-expressions-based URL rewriter for
>   IIS. It is compatible with Apache mod_rewrite making it possible to
>   move configurations from Apache to IIS and vice versa just by copying
>   .htaccess files (please see this compatibility chart). It is used for
>   search engine optimization, to proxy another server's content, stop
>   hotlinking or strengthen server security.